# John cannot use "--incremental:all" - No charset defined for mode: all

Tags: john-the-ripper

```
user@user:~/Asztal/$ john --stdout --incremental:all
No charset defined for mode: all
user@user:~/Asztal/$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.04
Release: 15.04
Codename: vivid
user@user:~/Asztal/$ dpkg -l | grep -i john
ii  john                                  1.8.0-2                                    amd64        active password cracking tool
ii  john-data                             1.8.0-2                                    all          active password cracking tool - character sets
user@user:~/Asztal/$
```

**Question**: how can I solve this? where can I give charset to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [OpenWall's examples](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/EXAMPLES.shtml), you should generate *chrset* files if you have none:

> If your "pot file" got large enough (or if you don't have any charset files at all), you might want to use it to generate a new set of main charset files:

```
makechr
```

Comment: `makechr: command not found`